# Move last row to first place using awk

Tags: awk

How can i move last row to first place using awk. thanks in advance.

input

```
a1 a2 a3 a4
1 2 3 4
0 0 0 0
2 3 3 3
```

output

```
a1 a2 a3 a4
2 3 3 3
1 2 3 4
0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Have you made an attempt to solve this yourself? What problems are you facing?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. We are glad to help you debug code or answer questions about difficult concepts but questions as broad as this one aren't a good fit for our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pure awk solution:

```
awk '{a[NR]=$0}END{for(i=1;i<NR;++i){if(i==2)print a[NR];print a[i]}}' file
a1 a2 a3 a4
2 3 3 3
1 2 3 4
0 0 0 0
```

Save all the lines to the array `a`, using the record number as the key. Loop through the array once the file is processed, inserting the last record `a[NR]` in the appropriate place.

In some versions of awk, `$0` still contains the last line of the file in the `END` block, so you can use it in place of `a[NR]` but this way is more widely compatible. Thanks to [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

one way to do it with awk is to process the file once and store the whole file content in memory, finally output again in expected order. The other two answers have shown how it worked.

Another way to do it is not saving the content, but go thru the file twice.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{e=$0;c=NR;next}FNR==2{print e}FNR!=c' file file
```

First go we remember the last line content and the last line number. The 2nd go, we output the text.

test:

```
kent$  cat f
title
1
2
3
4
5
6
7

kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{e=$0;c=NR;next}FNR==2{print e}FNR!=c' f f
title
7
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '{a[NR]=$0} END{print a[1] ORS a[NR]; for (i=2;i<NR;i++) print a[i]}' file
a1 a2 a3 a4
2 3 3 3
1 2 3 4
0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I first got the question completly wrong and needed to change it (after it was accepted already).

I finally ended up with the following, which is basically the same as [TomFenech's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29516417/171318) answer. Please accept his answer, since he posted that a long time ago..

```
# Append all lines to buffer
{
    a[NR]=$0
}

# Rearrange it at the end
END {
    for(i=1;i<NR;i++) {
        if(i==2) {
            print a[NR]
        }
        print a[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice thorough explanation but your script doesn't do the right thing!

Comment: eh, how is this accepted it is in the wrong order !

Comment: I wrote "let me check that" .. Please give me a chance to do so

Comment: @hek2mgl I wasn't saying it to you, i was wondering why OP has accepted it. Either they have posted the wrong output in their question or not tested this answer.

Comment: @JID No issues. It took me some time to change that.. I was thinking to complicated. Finally I ended up with a solution like `TomFenech`. He should receive the accept..

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks NR is guaranteed to work, a[NR] should work in this case. Changed that. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

Should work probably

```
tac file | awk 'x{print x}NR==1{y=$0;next}{x=$0}END{print y"\n"x}' | tac
```

#### Output

```
a1 a2 a3 a4
2 3 3 3
1 2 3 4
0 0 0 0
```